# What does "their" refer to here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does ***their*** refer to Bitcoin, Libra or The Winklevoss Twins?

> The inability for Facebook’s Libra to operate in a permissionless manner puts into question whether it should be considered a real cryptocurrency at all — at least in the minds of Bitcoin purists. The Winklevoss Twins, who formerly battled with Facebook CEO Mark Zuckerburg over control of the social media company, also felt the wrath of those who wish to stick with the decentralized, censorship-resistant nature of Bitcoin due to **their** association with a custodial, regulated cryptocurrency payments app that allows users to spend their Bitcoin and altcoins at Starbucks, Whole Foods, and other major retailers.

[Source](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ktorpey/2019/05/27/facebooks-upcoming-cryptocurrency-has-nothing-to-do-with-bitcoin/#7dc3d62b5d0b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Their' is the third person plural possessive determiner, meaning "belonging to or associated with the people or things previously mentioned or easily identified." Look backwards for something plural and previously mentioned. The only such thing is the Winklevoss twins. Note: when discussing siblings, families, etc, we do not capitalise words such as "twins", "brothers", etc.

Answer (score 0):

there are two 'their's in the text and it is ambiguous what the first one means. The sentence is quite a mess so lets break it down and remove all adjectives and in-sentence examples.

> The Winklevoss Twins,

the main subject of this sentence

> who formerly battled with Facebook CEO Mark Zuckerburg over control of the social media company,

additional information about the twins, you can ignore this part as it is basically a sentence on its own.

> also felt the wrath of those who wish to stick with the nature of Bitcoin

"Those who wish to stick with bitcoin" is the subject of this part of the sentence

> due to their association with a payments app that allows users to spend their Bitcoin at major retailers.

Here we come to the main part of the sentence, the description of the animosity. So the Their here refers to the main subject of the sentence, the twins.

I'd restructure the sentence to:

> the Winklevoss twins felt the wrath of those who wish to stick with Bitcoin due to the twins'association with a centralized payment app (explain the reasoning for the animosity here in three or four more sentences, end at comparable length).